# Why is "Image" not defined after PIL import

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

First time Python user, so apologies if I am misunderstanding something basic like how libraries are accessed (I am an R user).

Using a colleague's code (which works on his end) and trying to load the the following:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
```

results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Box\Py\Python3\Py3_StaticMain.py", line 32, in <module>
    from reportlab.lib import colors
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\colors.py", line 44, in <module>
    from reportlab.lib.utils import asNative, isStr, rl_safe_eval
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 389, in <module>
    haveImages = Image is not None
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

Pillow and reportlab are installed. After searching online I found similar error reports and the solution was to add this line prior to the previous library call (again, my colleague does need this on his end):

```
from PIL import Image
```

However, this did not fix the problem, the error persists. Also of note both these lines get greyed out by PyCharm which apparently means that these libraries are already loaded so these lines are unnecessary? It is counter intuitive that an unnecessary command would cause an error. The other libraries imported are os.path, sys, datetime, and tkinter. Also, even if I just put these two lines in a new py file I get the same behavior: greyed out and error.

Comment: I don't understand why you had to add `from PIL import Image`.  My version of `site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py` has that line already, near the top of the file.

Comment: If `from PIL import Image` works in your main program, then it has to work in reportlab.  You don't need it in your code, but if it works, that's enough.  That's exactly what they do.  How did you install Pillow?

Comment: This looks like a compatibility issue between the version of Pillow you have installed and the version of ReportLab you have installed - how did you set up your environment are you using a virtualenv? Did your colleague provide a requirements.txt file for you to install the dependencies from? You can check what versions of each you have by typing pip freeze into your terminal

Comment: @pzutils. Pillow==9.3.0,  reportlab==3.6.11. Project files are listed under "venv" 'folder' icon in PyCharm, so yes virtual environment?

Comment: @Tim Roberts Libraries were install in console using pip3 command.

Comment: But not in PyCharm?  Doesn't PyCharm have its own installation of Python?

Comment: @bmacwilliams you may want to try installing a version of Pillow earlier than 6.0 https://groups.google.com/g/reportlab-users/c/Qk4pCp2V9eI

Answer (score 0):

Not a very satisfying answer but after uninstalling and reinstalling both Python and the IDE everything worked.